# Jekyll _data: Data from .yml files displayed locally but not on github

Tags: github, jekyll

I have used Jekyll's [**_data** feature](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) to store short text messages inside .yml file.

For example, I have a file named `messages.yml` and inside it I have:

`hello: 'Hello world!'`

Inside my index.html file I have `<h1>{{ site.data.messages.hello }}</h1>`. When I run Jekyll server locally I get a nice output: `<h1>Hello world!</h1>` but once I merge changes inside **gh-pages** and check the github version of the site all I get is `<h1></h1>`.

Why the text from **_data** is not being rendered once the site is live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my attempt to simplify the question I have overlooked one crucial thing that (as it usually happens) was causing the problem.

I have messages in multiple languages and use **lang** variable stored inside page frontmatter to display the message in proper language.

For example, in my template I have this line:
`<p>{{ site.data.messages.[page.lang].hello }}</p>`

If page contains `lang: en` in frontmatter, the output will be `<p>Hello world!</p>`; if it contains `lang: es` ==> `<p>Hola mundo!</p>`. That works perfectly.

I've set the default *lang* values for all files inside **en** and **es** directories by using Jekyll's [**defaults** feature](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#frontmatter-defaults) **which is not supported in Jekyll 1.5.1** that [*gh-pages* currently use](https://pages.github.com/versions/). I was using the latest version of Jekyll 2.0.3.

I had to set the *lang* variable for each page to fix this.

I hope this answer helps someone. Sorry for the confusion.